# Unable to format date correctly in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My model property is like this

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}"), DisplayName("Procedure Effective From"),
     DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ProcedureEffectiveFrom { get; set; }
```

And in view

```
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProcedureEffectiveFrom, new { @class = "form-control date-picker" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProcedureEffectiveFrom)
```

And I am expecting an output like this

```
1/27/2015
```

But the output is

```
1/27/2015 10:40:45 AM
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProcedureEffectiveFrom, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control date-picker" })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `[DisplayFormat]` and `[DataType]` are only respected when using `@Html.DisplayFor()` and `@Html.EditorFor()`. You need to set the format using the overload that accepts a format string.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProcedureEffectiveFrom, "{0:MM dd, yyyy}" new { @class = "form-control date-picker" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}"),DisplayName("Procedure Effective From")]
      public DateTime ProcedureEffectiveFrom { get; set; }
```

in view use like

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProcedureEffectiveFrom, new { @class = "form-control date-picker" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProcedureEffectiveFrom)
```

and for displaying the date time use

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProcedureEffectiveFrom)
```

Comment: That will generate the browsers HTML5 date picker implementation (if supported by the browser) in which case it needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}` (ISO format)

Answer (score 1):

**In view** You may try this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProcedureEffectiveFrom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = m.ProcedureEffectiveFrom.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @class = "form-control" } })
```